# Normalization using mean and standard derivation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

I am really new to machine learning and I have a question which I couldn't find the answer so clear on the internet. I created a model and I have mean and standard derivation.
Now I want to normalize the data is by subtracting the mean from the individual predictors and dividing by the standard deviation.
I googled and I realized StandardScaler of sklearn set mean 0 for normalize. My question is that if there is a method to do this normalization or I just need to do the calculation by myself?

Comment: I do not understand your question, as you said you can use StandardScaler of sklearn to normalize (which means substract the mean and divides by std dev)

Comment: @alan.elkin because I searched how to use it but every where said this function set mean = 0

Answer (score 3):

When you subtract the mean from each element, the mean of the resulting set is, indeed, zero.  Similarly, dividing the resulting values by the sdev results in a set with a new sdev of 1.0 -- work through the algebra on each of these if you need to see the mechanics.

For the most part, that *is* the normalization process:

```
new_set = (old_set - mean) / sdev
```

where `new_set` and `old_set` are vectors.

Yes, there are methods to perform the normalization for you.  You need perhaps to widen your search terms, but particularly *narrow* them to your implementation paradigm.  Each package or ML framework will have its own normalization method(s).  If you can't find them, I hope that the standard linear transformation (above) will serve your purposes.